# Calling variables with twitter api

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, attributes, traceback

I have been working on a weather station, which I want to be able to automatically post current weather to twitter.  So far, I have been able to easily post regular strings such as `t.statuses.update(status= 'twitter post!')`
but whenever I attempt to post a variable, the current temperature for instance, I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/pi/Desktop/Python2Projects/MAIN.py", line 79, in 
>       t.statuses.update (status= 'Current temperature in dowd house: %d F \n Windspeed: %d mph' %(temp, vmph) ) AttributeError: 'int' object
>   has no attribute 'statuses'

Here is my code so far, the twitter post line is at the very bottom:

```
#sets up libraries
from sys import argv
import os
import glob
import subprocess
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import datetime

#Sets up twitter library
from twitter import *
access_token = 'secret'
access_token_secret = 'cant tell you'
consumer_key = 'i have to change all these'
consumer_secret = 'they usually have my twitter access keys'
t = Twitter(auth=OAuth(access_token, access_token_secret, consumer_key,     consumer_secret))

#sets up GPIO for windspeed Hall effect sensor
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.IN)

#sets up GPIO for temperature probe
os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')
base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[0]
device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'


#usus probe to take temperature
def read_temp_raw():
    catdata = subprocess.Popen(['cat',device_file],    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out,err = catdata.communicate()
    out_decode = out.decode('utf-8')
    lines = out_decode.split('\n')
    return lines

def read_temp():
    lines = read_temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        temp_f = temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0
        return float(temp_f) #float(temp_c)
temp = read_temp()

#setup for windspeed sensor
timy = datetime.datetime.now()
timx = datetime.datetime.now()
rotations = 0
#radious of windspeed sensor in meters
r = .1
#time in seconds you want sensor to collect data for average speed
t = 5

#main windspeed loop
timeout = time.time() + t
while True:
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(27, GPIO.BOTH)
    hallActive = GPIO.input(27)

    if time.time() > timeout:
        break
    elif( hallActive == False ):
        rotations = rotations + 1
    elif( hallActive == True ):
        pass

#function that converts rotations/s to mph
vmph = (r*6.28*rotations*2.2369) / t

GPIO.cleanup()

print 'Current temperature: %d F \n Windspeed: %d mph \n' %(temp, vmph)

t.statuses.update (status= 'Current temperature: %d F \n Windspeed: %d mph' %(temp, vmph) )
```

end of code

Thanks so much for any help or suggestions!  It's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this problem because you assigned `t` to the value `5` here:

```
#time in seconds you want sensor to collect data for average speed
t = 5
```

After that point, you try to do `t.statues` but of course that won't work, since `t` is an integer and not a reference to the twitter api.

The easy way to solve this problem is to change the name of the twitter api handle at the very top of your script:

```
twitter_api = Twitter(auth=OAuth(access_token,
                                 access_token_secret,
                                 consumer_key, consumer_secret))
```

Then at the bottom, adjust your code accordingly:

```
temp_line = 'Current temperature: %d F \n Windspeed: %d mph \n' %(temp, vmph) 

print(temp_line)

twitter_api.statuses.update(status=temp_line)
```

As a general rule, try to avoid single character named variables. They just add confusion to your code (as in this example) plus they make your code difficult to maintain in the future (for your, or anyone else that has to maintain it).

Python provides an excellent style guide, called [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) which has some guidelines on how to format your code.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't express how grateful I am.  This is my first coding project, so I'm trying to learn as I go.  Also thanks for giving me the link on formatting.  I knew very little on that before, but now ill start implementing all of that from now on.  Very much appreciated.